# Run Multiple Function on a Select Tag in Angular 10

Tags: angular, tags, html-select

I have a select tag in my HTML code:

```
 <select
  name="dater"
  id="dchange"
  style="height: 38px; width: 110px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: -32px;"
  class="custom-select form-control"
  change)="dateChange($event.target.value)" >
    <option  *ngFor="let i of days">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

The days array and the onchange event in my .ts code:

```
days = ["All", "Today", "Last 7 days", "Last 30 days"];

dateChange(deviceValue){
  switch(deviceValue){
    case "All":
    this.journals = this.journals;
    break;
    case "Today":
      this.journals = this.TodaysTrx;
      break;
      case "Last 7 days":
      this.journals = this.last7daysTrx;
      break;
      case "Last 30 days":
      this.journals = this.last30daysTrx;
      break;
      default:
      this.journals = this.journals;
  }
}
```

I discovered that if I select an option, the onchange event runs, if I decide to select another option, lets say "Last 30 days" the onchange event doesn't set my this.journals to this.last30daysTrx. It just remains in the first selected option, but it logs the changes in the console for every changes.

Comment: This working for me.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1d2ist

Answer (score 0):

just create one function including functions you need to call on change event and call that function in your template :)